# Overlapping Computation and Communication or I/O using OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, hpc

I am working on an HPC project where I am processing TBs of data from disk. The basic flow if represented by importing a subset of data on each node. Generating a bunch of other data and accumulating results, then exporting the results. The I/O I need to do is large and takes almost as much time as the computations. I was hoping to interleave the computation and communication. I really only know OpenMP. Below is a psudocode example of my attempt. However, the sections appear to be running serially.

Is there a way to force the sections to run in parallel?
Is there a better way to do this?

```
while ( There are still blocks of work available ) {

#pragma  omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        //Perform collective I/O 
        // Based on parallel HDF
        BigBlock block1 = ImportFunc();
    }

    #pragma omp section
    {
        while (While there are still subset blocks to process) {
            const SubSetBlock block2 = GenerateNextSubBlock(); //includes a parallel for loop

            #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) num_threads(omp_get_max_threads()-1)
            for (int i = 0; i < numVessels; ++i) {
                ProcessAllBlock2ItemsForABlock1Item(block1[i], block2);
            }

        }

    }
} //OMP Sections
}// while
```

Comment: *"However, the sections appear to be running serially."* - how did you determine that? Please share your observations as well as your system specification. It would also be easier to discuss if you can provide a [mcve].

Comment: did you enable nested parallelism? Hint, try to `export OMP_NESTED="true"`

Comment: @Zulan I will give it a go... but i don't know what I can do to be meaningful. Also in retrospect, it does seem to be overlapping the import and the computation. I was using timing information of the loop, structure and the individual components. The timing info includes a serial import and serial export block before and after the loop structure. This is included in the overall timing making it look like it was not properly running in parallel.

Comment: @Gilles I have a call to "omp_set_nested(1);" at the top of my main.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with large data sets I have found STXXL to be quite useful. It uses OpenMP under the hood and will saturate disk I/O if you can feed it data fast enough.

http://stxxl.org

Mike

Comment: The issue really isn't the datasets, it is about allowing me to use one of my 20 threads to interleave the calcs with the I/O (it is on the order of GBs per loop). I am talking about large files that are accessed with HDF5. This uses MPI I/O under the hood to allow me to leverage my Parallel NAS system in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If nesting is what you want, then you should set 
 `omp_set_max_active_levels(...)` (at least 2 in your case) **and** `omp_set_nested(true)`.

However, I would honestly suggest you use `std::future` in this case, it's very easy to use and will run your function on a separate thread (to be sure, you should pass it `std::launch::async` as the first argument). It is generally not as moody as OpenMP when it comes to nesting.

The call would be something like this

```
std::future<BigBlock> block1 = std::async(std::launch::async, ImportFunc, ...);
```

Where the `...` are any parameters you wish to pass to `ImportFunc`.

Once you need the data you call `block1.get()`, this will wait for the thread to finish if it hasn't, or simply return the data if it has. At that point I'd suggest you have a move constructor (you really don't want to copy it if it's big, then again you probably already have one for the `ImportFunc`, or you're passing pointers around, but in that case make sure you don't `delete` when the future gets destroyed if you create another instance of `BigBlock`) and just move it to another instance of `BigBlock` (i.e. the one your threads wish to operate on).

Comment: I like this a lot. I was looking for something more like this in the first place. I will give it a try.